# If we add a domain or forest functionality in the main DC then will it be replicated to the secondary DC as well?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

I added a recycle bin functionality in my primary domain controller, after that i tried to add that functionality on another domain controller connected to it. But an error shows that "the specified value already exist". So if we give a functionality to the forest level, then will it affect every DC in the forest?

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about the AD recycle bin, then yes.
Standard windows features and roles, no.